# Builder pattern for constructing an instance of a class that can have different types

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider the following product and AbstractBuilder from wikipedia:

```
/** "Product" */
class Pizza {
        private String dough = "";
        private String sauce = "";
        private String topping = "";

        public void setDough(String dough) {
                this.dough = dough;
        }

        public void setSauce(String sauce) {
                this.sauce = sauce;
        }

        public void setTopping(String topping) {
                this.topping = topping;
        }
}

/** "Abstract Builder" */
abstract class PizzaBuilder {
        protected Pizza pizza;

        public Pizza getPizza() {
                return pizza;
        }

        public void createNewPizzaProduct() {
                pizza = new Pizza();
        }

        public abstract void buildDough();

        public abstract void buildSauce();

        public abstract void buildTopping();
}
```

If you see the method `createNewPizzaProduct` in class `PizzaBuilder`.

If Pizza implemented an interface, say `Foo` and had to implement a method `bar`, how would the method `createNewPizzaProduct` account for this since there would be many different types of `Pizza`?

What would be the most elegant solution such that the pattern is not violated? This pattern is new to me.

Comment: Then I would have a `FooBuilder` instead of a `PizzaBuilder` and make all the builder methods return `Foo`. The `createNewPizzaProduct` method would instead be called `createNewFooProduct`.

Comment: @Adarshr So are you saying that I would have an abstract builder for all the different types of `Foo` instances? Also, shouldn't the `createNewFooProduct` method be made abstract then, since we want the concrete builders to implement this method for the different `Foo` instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createNewPizzaProduct` would not have to care whether the `Pizza` class implements specific methods: its sole responsibility is to instantiate a `Pizza`. If you're asking how it would deal with the possibility of having to create different Pizza implementations based on some criterion, then you'll want to look into the *Factory pattern*.

Comment: So the Builder pattern is not applicable here at all then?

Comment: Could I not just make the method `createNewPizzaProduct` abstract and then have different `Foo` builders implement this method? I'm not trolling, I'm simply trying to understand how I can approach this without violating the principles of this pattern

Comment: @Joeblackdev: The Builder pattern is perfectly compatible with the Factory pattern. As you say, you could have different builders produce different types of Pizza. You could make `createNewPizzaProduct` take an enum as a parameter, and switch on that. Or you could have it take an actual Class type, and produce the instance via reflection. Or you could inject a factory into PizzaBuilder that `createNewPizzaProduct` could use. There are lots of options, depending on your specific needs and preferences.